Power Automate - Create Folder and File - Place File inside of New Folder
I have a flow that triggers when a specific mailbox receives an email.  The flow then creates a folder in a library based on the Email's Subject line, then Creates a file out of that email, then is supposed to add that file to the new folder.  So far I've only been able to create the folder, then the file separately.  
Even so, the file that gets created isn't correct.  I basically just want to create a folder, then add the email to that folder as a file (with attachments).  How can I get that done?
Thank you!

See the screenshots below. As Kristaps mentioned, need to use Full Path from the output of Create new folder step.



When creating files, you are using "Folder Path" as path for item.
That seems to be wrong since that property holds path to the folder {Path}, not a destination {FullPath}. If you are using {Path} files will be created at same level where folder is, not within it.
Example of  properties for new folder "London"
{Path}     : Lists/Invoices/ProjectA
{FullPath} : Lists/Invoices/ProjectA/London

